# Add existing wildcard SSL certificate to Amazon EC2 Nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl

I'm trying to add a pre-existing wildcard SSL certificate to a single Ubuntu instance on Amazon EC2, where the webserver is Nginx, and I run a single subdomain.

I have - from the original vendor who provides the certificate - files named private.key, selfsigned.crt, and ssl-shared-cert.inc. I've uploaded these files to EC2, at /etc/nginx/ssl (which is a new folder I've created). I've previously used the same files on Heroku, though the process seems to be quite specific there. They're also used on our main domain (https://wwww.minnpost.com), but I was not involved in setting them up there, as I believe our hosting vendor did it for us.

ssl-shared-cert looks like this:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/selfsigned.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/private.key"
```

On my EC2 instance, I've changed my site's configuration to:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name subdomainurl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;
    root path;
    ...
}
```

When I run `sudo nginx -t` I get the following:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

So I ran `sudo service nginx restart`, and this returned OK. First I checked to make sure the HTTP version still worked, and it does, but the HTTPS still does not. When I run curl, it returns:

```
* SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

Where can I go from here?

Comment: If it's self-signed then the certificate is not going to be trusted.  What is `ssl-shared-cert.inc`?

Comment: @DerfK I added some more info. As I've been researching, I have wondered why it's called self-signed, as it does appear to be trusted when it gets used on our other sites. I'm a bit confused there. But in any case, I've also added the contents of ssl-shared-cert.inc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the certificate is *not* actually self-signed then there's two possibilities that I can think of.  The first is that curl is missing the bundle of trusted authorities (Debian keeps a set of trusted certs in a package named `ca-certificates`).  If this is the case then no https site would work with it.  Can you check that your curl is working with other sites?

If curl is working then what you are missing is likely the chain of certificates that the signer should have provided that links the signature on your certificate with one of the primary trusted certificates. [From the instructions here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains) you should add the certificate chain (with each certificate in PEM format) to the *end* of `selfsigned.crt` (the server's own certificate must be first).

Comment: Depending on where the cert is from most of the chain certificates can be downloaded from the CA website

Comment: Curl does seem to work well with other HTTPS sites. I'll give the chain of certificates a try.

Comment: Sigh. I think I missed the boat entirely, and the certificate file I uploaded was the self-signed version. I found more files from the host, and it seemed to work. This was the right track for sure, though. Will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

What DerkK said about self signed certificates is absolutely right. You need a different certificate. I have a [tutorial about Let's Encrypt and Nginx here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/) - it's relatively simple.